# Как находясь в eventFilter узнать текущий self.input.text()?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlineedit, qtimer, eventfilter

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QLineEdit, QApplication


class Ghost(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 200, 1000, 700)

        self.input = QLineEdit(self)
        self.input.move(150, 15)
        self.input.resize(820, 20)
        self.input.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if source == self.input and event.type() == 6:
            print(self.input.text() + event.text(), self.input.text() + event.text() == 'all')
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Ghost()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Если ввести 'all', то условие выполнится, но если вести 'alll' + удалить символ('\x08') то нет. 
Как это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QLineEdit, QApplication, \
        QWidget, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import QEvent, QTimer


class Ghost(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralwidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)         
        
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.resize(400, 200)

        self.input = QLineEdit(self)
        self.input.installEventFilter(self)
        
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.input)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if source == self.input and event.type() == QEvent.KeyPress:         # 6
#            print(self.input.text()+event.text(), self.input.text()+event.text() == 'all')
# !!! +++
            QTimer.singleShot(0, self.key_press)                             # !!! +++

        return super().eventFilter(source, event)

# !!! +++  vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
    def key_press(self):
        print(f"input.text() = {self.input.text()} == 'all' ==> {self.input.text() == 'all'} ")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Ghost()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]